# CMake + Visual Studio 2019: error invalid argument '/Wno-narrowing'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded the source code for a library that resembles the processing library but for c++ called [libxd](https://github.com/bernhardfritz/libxd). I used CMake to generate project files for Visual Studio 2019 which worked successfully. When trying to compile the solution for all of the provided build modes, I get the following errors:

[image: vs errors]

The first error `invlaid numeric argument '/Wno-narrowing'` is what I'm concerned about for now. I'm trying to figure out why this argument is being provided to the compiler. When looking in the properties window for the `xd` project in the solution I can see the command line arguments that are supposed to be provided to the compiler in the `C/C++ > Command Line` tab. I verified that there is no `/Wno-narrowing` option provided. When looking at the build output it can be seen that the option `-Wno-narrowing` is being provided to the compiler. Can someone help me figure out why this argument is being passed? I looked throughout the compiler properties window to see if I could see anything that would be affecting it but I can't see anything that would affect this.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /IC:\dev\libxd\include /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\glad\include /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\glm /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\stb\include /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\glfw\include /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"xd.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"xd.dir\Debug\xd.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:prompt  -Wno-narrowing C:\dev\libxd\src\opensans.cpp
Tracking command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Tracker.exe /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\FileTracker\FileTracker32.dll" /i C:\dev\libxd\build\xd.dir\Debug\xd.tlog /r C:\DEV\LIBXD\SRC\OPENSANS.CPP /b MSBuildConsole_CancelEventfa83e1bb599743cfa0c02eb67d579e28  /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe"  /c /IC:\dev\Users\olive\Downloads\libxd\include /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\glad\include /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\glm /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\stb\include /IC:\dev\libxd\lib\glfw\include /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"xd.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"xd.dir\Debug\xd.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:prompt  -Wno-narrowing C:\dev\libxd\src\opensans.cpp
cl : command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wno-narrowing'
The command exited with code 2.
```

Comment: "Can someone help me figure out why this argument is being passed?" - Because the project does that, see its [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/bernhardfritz/libxd/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L48). CMake is able to change `-` to `/` when adapt options for `cl` compiler. But CMake is not aware whether the option is actually supported by the compiler.

Comment: Unfortunately it's very easy to use CMake in a non-portable way. The project you're trying to build is an example of a project that doesn't support MSVC (but you can fork it and improve it).

Comment: Ah thanks. I removed that line from the file and rebuilt it with success (albeit with a bunch of narrowing warnings).

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because that's not a valid MSVC flag. The flag is there because the CMakeLists.txt file demands it:

```
set_source_files_properties(src/opensans.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -Wno-narrowing)
```

That project specifies [what it supports](https://github.com/bernhardfritz/libxd/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) for building under Windows and it's *not* MSVC.

> Windows Prerequisites: ***mingw-w64 version >= 4.8.1***

So you either need to build it in the supported way, or modify the build scripts to allow for MSVC.

That would entail figuring out what the flag does in `gcc` (disables diagnostic messages about narrowing issues) and finding the equivalent in MSVC, probably a `/disable:nnnn` variant, once you figure out the `nnnn`. Figuring that out should be relatively painless since MSVC will tell you that when you compile it - lots of `Cnnnn - something to do with narrowing` warning messages.

Or you could just disable the line that adds the flag (for MSVC builds only) and see if it still builds. Of course, in the spirit of open source, you should then notify the author what it took to get it going, they *may* be happy to support MSVC if the effort is not too high.